# CQRS/ES - User Login from Read Or From Write Side

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I am building a user login and authentication in CQRS with event sourcing.(with AXON Framework)

Follwing are the steps in my model -

1. **User Registration Flow** -

   ```
   UserRegistrationCommand handles the user registration , since the 
   application makes the uniqueness between users using email , means only one 
   user can register with one email. (For this I was maintaining the table on 
   read side , which contains the registered email address. So when user tries 
   to register ,We query the read side for the validation of email address 
   from client side (not from the write side),and show a message "This email 
   is already register").

   When the client validation passes ,the UserRegistrationCommand is issued and 
   handled by the command handler , which then fires an event called 
   UserRegistredEvent , and this event is handled by the event handler on read 
   side and updates the read side DB.
   ```

   **2. UserLogin Flow -**
   I am bit confused about the UserLogin.

   I have two  approaches in my mind:

   First Approach -

   ```
   User login using the read side, means user enters the username and 
   password. And this username and password is validated from read side, and   
   UserLogedInEvent is fired from the read side and catched by the write side and is
   saved in event store.
   ```

But I  have never seen in any architecture diagram that read side fires and event and handle by write side.

**So can i do that ?**

Second Approach -

```
 User login using write side , means the user issues UserLogingCommand 
 and before the command dispatch to command handler , we validate the 
 username and password using the read side by accessing the same public api 
 of read side (which was used in first approach).
```

But the problem is that , we cannot use the read side in write side (as I read 
   and know in cqrs architecture).
   But since I am using public API of read side, so I can think , it may be 
   correct.

So which approach you guys suggest OR there is some other approach to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we cannot use the read side in write side (as I read and know in cqrs architecture)

That's not quite right.  There's nothing wrong with using read side data when computing a write -- you just need to be aware of the *latency*.

> I have never seen in any architecture diagram that read side fires and event and handle by write side

It's a common enough pattern - a subscriber watches for changes in the read models, and computes commands to send to write models.  If you search for "process manager" and "event driven architecture" you may find the diagrams you are looking for.

For example, Alice places an order.  So we write that down in the order book, and as a consequence fire messages to the billing service and the fulfillment service.

> So which approach you guys suggest

Honestly? Buy a commodity solution for login and authentication and move on to a problem that has value to the core business.

But if you are rolling your own, I think you need to have a hard look at what your latency requirements actually are, and work from there.

Comment: Thumbs up on buying login and auth logic.  There's no competitive advantage there.  Use your time to improve the special sauce your company provides.

Comment: It is not only about the authentication , I want to clear the confusion using the above question. So that I can use CQRS correctly to build my application

Comment: In these times I'd fully agree with not writing your own login/authentication solution, but grabbing an off the shelve version of it all.

There is nothing wrong with trying to answer your CQRS thoughts/issues with login/authentication as the domain of course, that's true too.